# How to split a column in Pandas data frame into two and keeping the rest intact

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame constructed this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""probegenes,sample2,sample3,sample4
1415777_at Pnliprp1,20,10,11
1415805_at Clps,17,13,55"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
```

It looks like this:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
            probegenes  sample2  sample3  sample4
0  1415777_at Pnliprp1       20       10       11
1      1415805_at Clps       17       13       55
```

What I want to do is to split `probe genes` column so that it becomes like this:

```
       probe     genes     sample2  sample3  sample4
  1415777_at     Pnliprp1   20       10       11
  1415805_at     Clps       17       13       55
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column `probegenes` and create columns `probe`, `genes` and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) `probegenes`:

```
df[['probe', 'genes']] = df['probegenes'].str.split(" ", expand=True)
df = df.drop('probegenes', axis=1)
#change ordering of columns
print df[['probe','genes','sample2','sample3','sample4']]
        probe     genes  sample2  sample3  sample4
0  1415777_at  Pnliprp1       20       10       11
1  1415805_at      Clps       17       13       55
```

Or use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1= df['probegenes'].str.split(" ", expand=True)
df1.columns = ['probe', 'genes']
print df1
        probe     genes
0  1415777_at  Pnliprp1
1  1415805_at      Clps

print df.iloc[:,1:]
   sample2  sample3  sample4
0       20       10       11
1       17       13       55

print pd.concat([df1, df.iloc[:,1:]], axis=1)
        probe     genes  sample2  sample3  sample4
0  1415777_at  Pnliprp1       20       10       11
1  1415805_at      Clps       17       13       55
```